# Create a circular disc (an easier way)

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

To create the disc shown in the image, I added a circle with a triangle fan. Into edit mode, select the outer edges and extrude with cancel. Scale the new edges outside of the original edges. Then, select the original edge and slide it towards the center. And finally, I added several edge loops.

It seems a long way around. Is there an easier way?

[image: circular mesh]

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27968/how-to-add-edge-loops-to-a-circle-triangle-fan?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. I used the subdivide method. How do I give a like or select question answered as I don't see where on here. Thank you again